# async/await not debuggable in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have a React project setup using Create React App and the Typescript/React template. Everything seems to be working fine except for when I try to debug async/await functions.

The Chrome dev tools either have the breakpoints greyed out inside the async functions or when I try to click on a breakpoint (like line 6 below) it immediately moves the breakpoint to the line where the variable is set (to line 5).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Chrome devtools]

Comment: Is that the actual source or are you transpiling and using a source map? On a related note; does adding `debugger;` in the function body itself actually work?

Comment: `debugger` should always work.

Comment: Press `ctrl+o` and type the file name.  There are likely 2 files with the same name.  The breakpoints will work in one but not the other.  At least that has been my experience.

Comment: @apokryfos its using sourcemaps

Comment: @zero298 that did not work. I was able to set the breakpoints by using the second file but the debugger never hits them when I click the button the async functions are attached to.

Comment: Sometimes I get similar issues with my source maps. Usually wiping them and building fresh helps. If not I change them to inline source maps though this should not be used in production